# firebase functions check sub child name is exists?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hello i am trying to write a function that find all username below userid and decide the username already exists or not

my json looks like this

```
    {
  "ali": {
    "AccessToken": "asdadas",
    "CreatedAt": "2017/12/09",
    "DeletedAt": -1,
    "Email": "sadadada",
    "FirstName": "asdad",
    "LastName": "asdadad",
    "LoginType": 0,
    "Phone": "",
    "ThumbNailUrl": "",
    "UpdatedAt": -1,
    "UserName": "asdada"
  },
  "asdadad": {
    "AccessToken": "asdadas",
    "CreatedAt": "2017/12/09",
    "DeletedAt": -1,
    "Email": "asdadadada",
    "FirstName": "asdada",
    "LastName": "asdada",
    "LoginType": 0,
    "Phone": "",
    "ThumbNailUrl": "",
    "UpdatedAt": -1,
    "UserName": "asdadadada"
  }
}
```

my functions looks like this

```
    exports.CheckUserName = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    const userName = req.query.userName;
    if (userName == "" || userName == null) {
        return res.json({
            result: "UserName can not be null or empty"
        })
    } else {
        // what i have to do in here :(
    }
})
```

i tried a lot of way but i couldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm java developer so i'll tell you the logic. you can implement in your javascript

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userId");

rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("your username")) {
      // run some code
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can find all `username` under `id`.
If exists print something according to your need

If you don't know id
you can save all usernames in separate node called `usernames`
and put all `usernames` in there and always check from there if `usernames` exists in that node or not. pretty simple :)

Comment: but there is no column has userId

Comment: User id is changing for every person

Comment: pass the userId in child as a string !

Comment: accprding to your question,
you need to find all username below user id so i wrote code for that

Comment: i cant im searching the username in all users

Comment: @ALKINÇAKIRALAR check updated answer

Comment: cant i find another solution ? 
because i will check email too 
i dont know can i use foreach like something for this ?

Comment: if you're using firebase authentication you don't need to check email from database .. if already signed up it will not sign up again with same email